# Freeswitch performance improved after changing default password

Tags: freeswitch

I am new to Freeswitch.

After default installation of Freswitch 1.4, I noticed big latency while performing simple telephony operations.
i.e. when I called one extension from another, the called number started ringing 10 seconds after initialization of call. Same happened with conference bridge, it took 10 seconds for a callee to enter in conference.

Same time my colleague's Freeswitch was performing well. I inquired him and came to know he only changed default password.

To my surprise when I did that my Freeswitch was faster than light.

It looks a weired case.

Is it default behavior of Freswitch?

Can anyone from Freeswitch elaborate what happened in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Got answer from Freeswitch Team member Anthony Minessale II :

> The sample configuration you install when you setup FreeSWITCH actually has an extension that executes sleep 10 when you have the default password set. It also has a large warning message on your console explaining that you should not leave you system running with the default config unless you at least change the default password.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the default password because `FreeSwitch` will be paused for approximately `10s` if you're still using the default config.

Just change the default config and the delay will be gone.