# FreeSwitch Simplest configuration

Tags: freeswitch

I've installed FreeSwitch and managed to get it up and running on CentOS 6. I can connect to my instance using a SIP application (X-Lite) and make calls between extensions.
What I've done is used the out of the box default configuration but it seems to me the default configuration is too much for my purpose.
I want my instance only connect internal extensions, there is no calling outside, there is no real dial plans, simplest of all. I like to be able different extensions to call each other, not even voice mail is required.
I was wondering if there is a simplest configuration I can use. The reason I need this is the default configuration is not fast enough and when an extension makes a call to the next it takes around 5 seconds before I heard the ringing and I was hoping by disabling all the features I don't really need I can make this process faster.

So the question is:
1) Is there a bare bone simplest configuration I can use?
2) Is really the cause of the delay I see in configuration or there might be other reasons?

Again remember this is a out of the box installation, all I've done checked out the code and built the code and run the instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be this would some help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931085/freeswitch-performance-improved-after-changing-default-password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:
https://github.com/voxserv/freeswitch_conf_minimal/blob/tutorials/docs/tutorial_01_simple_pbx.md

This is my tutorial based on the minimal configuration that is available in the same git repository. Feel free to use it for your own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The delay you're seeing (usually 10 seconds), is usually because you still have the default password unchanged.  Either change the password (1234), or comment out the sleep line from your /dialplan/default.xml file:

```html
<condition field="${default_password}" expression="^1234$" break="never">
    <action application="log" data="CRIT WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING "/>
    <action application="log" data="CRIT Open $${conf_dir}/vars.xml and change the default_password."/>
    <action application="log" data="CRIT Once changed type 'reloadxml' at the console."/>
    <action application="log" data="CRIT WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING "/>
    <action application="sleep" data="10000"/>
</condition>
```